# Changes by David Bowie chord analysis

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, analysis

I am trying to find out what is going on in David Bowie’s “Changes” song in terms of the chords are used. I have made a couple observations but I want to make sure they're right.
[image: "Changes" score]

Firstly,the second measure(Db6) looks Like a chromatic passing chord to go Cmaj7 to Dm7

Secondly there is also a diatonic passing chord (G)on the 11th measure that helps transition F to another F chord

I just want to make sure that I’m right with my observations and I want to know anything else that I missed.

Comment: G is the dominant. I-iii-IV-V is about as standard as you can get.

Comment: @PiedPiper - But what about I-iii-IV-**V-IV**? While I'd also argue that the G chord in Bar 11 has a dominant function, it looks like the same dominant function as the V chord in the 12-bar blues (notably the IV-I-I-V-IV-I portion).

Comment: @Dekkadeci The song gets to the dominant by one standard progression and back to the tonic by another (V-IV-I). Nothing unusual.